# Speech Recognition/Dictation Crashing

Tags: macos, voice-dictation

```
Process:               com.apple.SpeechRecognitionCore.speechrecognitiond [8448]
Path:                  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpeechRecognitionCore.framework/Versions/A/XPCServices/com.apple.SpeechRecognitionCore.brokerd.xpc/Contents/XPCServices/com.apple.SpeechRecognitionCore.speechrecognitiond.xpc/Contents/MacOS/com.apple.SpeechRecognitionCore.speechrecognitiond
Identifier:            com.apple.SpeechRecognitionCore.speechrecognitiond
Version:               2.2.7 (2.2.7)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           com.apple.SpeechRecognitionCore.brokerd [738]

OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.11.4 (15E65)

Crashed Thread:        2  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-qos

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000000000cf0ac
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
```

Dictation fails without notification, system log reveals above crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps to resolve the crash:

1. Turn off enhanced dictation under the dictation system preference pane
2. Turn off dictation
3. Delete en_US.SpeechRecognition/ in /System/Library/Speech/Recognizers/SpeechRecognitionCoreLanguages/
4. Turn on dictation and enhanced dictation, the recognizer is downloaded again
5. Kill the speechsynthesisd and speechrecognitiond processes if dictation popup shows loading indefinitely